# How do i check the value of checkbox

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

i have a issue here.

I have a check box and i need to know his true value i think this always return true even if the checkbox is unchecked. What would better way to do this?

```
   private bool _marketingInfo;

  public bool MarketingInfo(Checkbox checkbox)
        {
            if (checkBoxMarketing.IsChecked)
            {
                _marketingInfo = true;
            }
            else
            {
                _marketingInfo = false;
            }

            return _marketingInfo = true;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

public bool MarketingInfo(Checkbox checkbox)
{

return checkBoxMarketing.IsChecked
}

Comment: You can improve your answer by adding an explanation and adding formatting for block code